# How to replace some values if a user already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't know how to replace some data if a "user" already exists.

I've tried `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I came to realize that this will probably not work. Because the only value that isn't updated is 'user' in my code but the other 3 values are constantly updated every 5 minutes.

```
INSERT INTO online ( `user`, `bot`, `world`, `status` ) VALUES ('$User', '$Name', '$World', '$status')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bot = VALUES ('$Name'), world = VALUES ('$World'), status = VALUES ('$status')
```

The idea is if, for example, user "bob" already exists update his other 3 values `bot`, `world`, `status`, instead of creating a new line and so on.

Edit: this is how I have it setup in [Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSlOT.png)

Comment: If the primary key is `user`, this will work as you want. Also, just looking at your code, you probably want to familiarise yourself with [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah i've googled around with primary key but as its a text it dsn't seem like i can make it primary hmm

edit: just noticed i could change it to varchar and then make it primary

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(30)` or some sane length as opposed to text.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `VALUES()` should be the name of a column, not a string. You put the name of the column that you would have inserted into.

```
INSERT INTO online ( `user`, `bot`, `world`, `status` ) VALUES ('$User', '$Name', '$World', '$status')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bot = VALUES (bot), world = VALUES (world), status = VALUES (status)
```